# "peer not authenticated" even after importing project specific certificate to keystore

Tags: java, spring, maven, java-8, backend

- Java version - 1.8
- Maven version - 3.1.0

After import certificate option using **keytool command** in my **jdk-security folder** under **cacerts** and **jssecarcets**, getting following error when running `mvn clean install`

I tried all the steps related to importing certificates. Using `-Djavax.net.debug=SSL` I verified that my certificate is being imported like all other valid ones.

Comment: First I strongly recommend to upgrade your Maven version to the most recent one because [Maven 3.1.0 is about 10 years old](https://maven.apache.org/docs/history.html) ... also the question is which version of JDK you are using ?

Comment: Okay..I will try with upgrading maven..also I am using jdk 8.